# mapAccumR -like recursion scheme over Fix?

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I'm playing with the functions from [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#t:Recursive), and struggling to figure out if it offers something that generalized `mapAccumR`. Something powerful enough to implement e.g.:

```
f :: [Int] -> (Int,[Int])
f [] = (0,[]) 
f (x:xs) = let (sz,xs') = f xs in (sz+x, x*sz : xs')
```

...in a single pass for a `Fix`-ed structure, like:

```
data L a as = Empty | C a as

input :: Fix (L Int)
input = Fix (C 1 (Fix (C 2 (Fix Empty))))
```

[`zygo`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:zygo) seems to be nearly what I want, except that I need access to the final `b` (the final sum in the example above).

My actual use case is type-checking an AST while annotating, and returning the type of the expression.

Comment: What sort of type signature are you hoping for?

Comment: Also, you should probably look at `para`.

Comment: But back to my first question, `mapAccumR` is a known concept for `Traversable` functors; it's much less clear what its supposed to mean for fixed points of arbitrary types.

Comment: Right so I think `para` is powerful enough to implement `f` but in quadratic time which I don't want. I think I could also do two `cata`, one to tag and accumulate sizes, and the next to strip those sizes from the subtrees again, but I also don't want to do that. You're right, probably if I thought hard about a signature I'd be most of the way to answering my own question, but I think I've decided this is all rather silly anyway

Comment: It looks like what I'm after is `zygo`; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36911924/176841)

Comment: Argh, except I need to capture that final `b` at the top level... hm, maybe that's hiding in `gzygo`; not sure.

Comment: The documentation for `recursion-schemes` is really superb. Immediately obvious that `zygo` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You want to descend upwards through `Fix f` tweaking values, while keeping track of a state as mapAccumR does? That's `cataM` for the upward order, with the `State` monad for the state to be kept track of. In your example:

```
f :: Fix (L Int) -> (Fix (L Int), Int)
f = (`runState` 0) $ cataM $ ((.) . fmap) Fix $ \case
  Empty -> pure Empty
  C x xs -> do
    sz <- get
    put $ sz+x
    return $ C (x*sz) xs
```

Using `lens`:

```
makeClassyPrisms ''L

f = (`runState` 0) . transformMOf . _Fix . _C . _1 $ \x -> do
  sz <- id <<+= x
  return $ x*sz
```

All untested.

Or do you want the state to be local to each branch?

Comment: Thanks, my actual example is an AST where I'm type-checking and annotating the tree in one pass. So at each level we need access to child types and return a type for the parent. Here's some points though, I appreciate the answer