# An example for chronomorphism

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

I don't understand how can I create some example with chronomorphism. 
I know about hylomorphism (`cata`, `ana`) also I know about `histo` and `futu`.

But I don't realize some example for chronomorphism (maybe some behavior as in Tardis monad).

Also related link https://github.com/ekmett/recursion-schemes/issues/42

This isn't related with [Histomorphisms, Zygomorphisms and Futumorphisms specialised to lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851766/histomorphisms-zygomorphisms-and-futumorphisms-specialised-to-lists) because doesn't has some example with chronomorphism.

Comment: perhaps putting the question at haskell-cafe@haskell.org can help

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37002861/2789312

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/e5debcaf531838eb6e2afd3ef3b34d60

Comment: This isn't duplicate. because no example with chrono in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851766/histomorphisms-zygomorphisms-and-futumorphisms-specialised-to-lists

Comment: I'm reopening this question. One can debate the merits of the question on its own, but while it's similar to the linked question it's definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the biggest use of chronomorphisms is collapsing a named syntax tree. In particular, you can refer to names that haven't been processed yet as well as names that *have* already been processed.

Another thing you can do with chronomorphisms is rewrite dynamorphisms! You can read more about dynamorphisms [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=BA4CCC586864C57099F3D7092439228C?doi=10.1.1.416.2381&rep=rep1&type=pdf). One of the examples they cite is the Catalan numbers. I've translated it to Haskell below.

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Comonad.Cofree

dyna :: (Functor f) => (f (Cofree f a) -> a) -> (c -> f c) -> c -> a
dyna a c = extract . h where h = (uncurry (:<)) . (a &&& id) . fmap h . c

natural :: Int -> ListF Int Int
natural 0 = Nil
natural n = Cons n (n - 1)

takeCofree :: Int -> Cofree (ListF Int) a -> [a]
takeCofree 0 _ = []
takeCofree _ (a :< Nil) = [a]
takeCofree n (a :< Cons _ c) = a : takeCofree (n - 1) c

catalan :: Int -> Int
catalan = dyna coa natural where
    coa :: ListF Int (Cofree (ListF Int) Int) -> Int
    coa Nil = 1
    coa (Cons x table) = sum $ zipWith (*) xs (reverse xs)
        where xs = takeCofree x table
```

You might also find [this](http://blog.sumtypeofway.com/recursion-schemes-part-iv-time-is-of-the-essence/) useful. It has an example that uses a futumorphism to build a tree and a catamorphism to tear it down (though this is occluded). Of course, this map is in fact another specialization of the chronomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, but looks like your code doesn't work. Could you please provide working version?

Comment: I don't understand why the histomorphism for Catalan numbers given in that paper is called a bogus solution, even though it gives correct results in Haskell? Why is converting the coinductive argument to the `elems` function to a simple inductive list bogus? Is it only bogus in languages with stronger type systems like Agda?